# List generation via Array in Wolfram Language

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I have a code where we first need to generate n + 1 numbers in a range with a given step. However, I don't understand how and why it works:

```
a = 2;
b = 7;
h = (b-a)/n;

x[0] = a;
Array[x, n+1, 0];

For[i = 0, i < n + 1, i++, x[i] = a + h*i]
```

My questions are:

1. Are elements of x automatically generated when accessed? There's no mention of x before the line x[0] = a
2. Shouldn't index access be like x[[i]]?
3. What exactly does Array do here? It isn't assigned to anything which confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, [Array[*f, n, r*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) generates a list using the index origin *r*.

On its own `Array[x, n + 1, 0]` just produces a list of `x` functions, e.g.

```
n = 4;
Array[x, n + 1, 0]
```

> {x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}

If `x` is defined it is applied, e.g.

```
x[arg_] := arg^2

Array[x, 4 + 1, 0]
```

> {0, 1, 4, 9, 16}

Alternatively, to use `x` as a function variable the Array can be set like so

```
Clear[x]

With[{z = Array[x, n + 1, 0]}, z = {m, n, o, p, q}]

{x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}
```

> {m, n, o, p, q}

The OP's code sets function variables of `x` in the `For` loop, e.g.

Still with `n = 4`

```
a = 2;
b = 7;
h = (b - a)/n;

For[i = 0, i < n + 1, i++, x[i] = a + h*i]
```

which can be displayed by `Array[x, n + 1, 0]`

> {2, 13/4, 9/2, 23/4, 7}

also `x[0] == 2`

> True

The same could be accomplished thusly

```
Clear[x]

With[{z = Array[x, n + 1, 0]}, z = Table[a + h*i, {i, 0, 4}]]
```

> {2, 13/4, 9/2, 23/4, 7}

Note also `DownValues[x]` shows the function definitions

> {HoldPattern[x[0]] :> 2,
> HoldPattern[x[1]] :> 13/4,
> HoldPattern[x[2]] :> 9/2,
> HoldPattern[x[3]] :> 23/4,
> HoldPattern[x[4]] :> 7}

Answer (score 3):

Try `Range[2,10,2]` for a range of numbers from 2 to 10 in steps of 2, *etc*.

Beyond that there some faults in your code, or perhaps in your understanding of *Mathematica* ...

`x[0] = a` defines a function called `x` which, when presented with argument `0` returns `a` (or `a`'s value since it is previously defined).  *Mathematica* is particular about the bracketing characters used `[` and `]` enclose function argument lists. Since there is no other definition for the function `x` (at least not that we can see here) then it will return unevaluated for any argument other than `0`.

And you are right, doubled square brackets, *ie* `[[` and `]]`, are used to enclose index values. `x[[2]]` would indeed refer to the second element of a list called `x`. Note that *Mathematica* indexes from `1` so `x[[0]]` would produce an error if `x` existed and was a list.

The expression `Array[x, n+1, 0]` *does* return a value, but it is not assigned to any symbol so is lost.  And the trailing `;` on the line suppresses *Mathematica's* default behaviour to print the return value of any expression you execute.

Finally, on the issue of the use of `For` to make lists of values, refer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica.  And perhaps ask further *Mathematica* questions at that site, the real experts on the system are much more likely to be found there.

I suppose I might add ... if you are committed to using `Array` for some reason ask another question specifically about that.  As you might (not) realise, I recommend not using that function to create a list of numbers.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This code was given me in an example of Lagrange interpolation, it just didn't feel good and clear to me, I myself have shallow understanding of the language. So if there are better alternatives to this Array method I'm more than happy to use them instead